# disable button not working after download file asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code to download a file from the server to the client, that occurs when the button `btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel` is clicked, after that I want to have the button disable, how can I achieve that?

```
string fileName = newFN + ".xlsx";
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
                Response.TransmitFile(DestFile);                    
                Response.End();
btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel.Enabled = false;
```

I noticed that the button did not become disable when placed the above code (Response), cause I had another code there and the button became disable with it. So it must be something related with the Response.

**EDIT:**

The button is within a `ModalPopupExtender` in case it matters.

Comment: Be aware of the file name that you are specifying in the Content-Disposition header.  If the value contains a comma certain browsers won't like it.  Best to encode the file name or wrap it in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem, credit goes to: Dave Ward [(click here)](http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel" runat="server" 
                    OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;"
                    UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                    Text="Save results to DB and export to Excel"   
                    onclick="btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel_Click" />
```

this does the trick:
`OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;"`
`UseSubmitBehavior="false"`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that if you disable the button with server code you need to return the response to the browser window.

Here you return a stream that is captured by the browser as a file instead of to the browser window so the current display is never updated.

To get around this you can implement a javascript line on the button in the html itself.

You can use Attribute.Add() in code at Page_Load, f.ex:

```
btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel.Attribute.Add("onclick","this.disabled=true")
```

Comment: The difference is that the javascript is installed at the button before it is clicked so it is available before clicking it.. When you then click the button it will be disabled before next postback occurs.

Comment: I'm having issues here with your solution, since I have the button within a `ModalPopupExtender`. I can't get the button disable :(

Comment: In that case, check out the OnOkScript property on the extension.

Answer (score 1):

There at least two possible solutions.
1) Instead of writing a file to the response you can generate file in the temp directory on the server and give the user the link to this file (or redirect to this link).

2) If you want use writing to the response, you can create new Generate.aspx page that writes the file to the response in its `Page_Load` method.

```
if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)  
{
    //find file by its ID
    ...
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName));
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(fullFileName);
    Response.End();
}
```

On page with your btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel in `Page_Load` add this code:

```
var script = @"<script language=JavaScript>function Export(fileID)
{
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = 'Generate.aspx?ID='+ fileID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
</script>";

Page.RegisterStartupScript("Startup", script);
```

And then just call javascript `Export` method to send file to the user.

Comment: Hi Alexander, your first approach is what I do, but how to redirect to the file's link when click the button?  as you can see, I have the file path

Comment: Have you tried just redirect the user to the file? `Response.Redirect(http://yoursite.com/generated/f7401466-40ac-4150-b45a-9fa9dc40a9d8/file.xlsx)` ?

Comment: ok, I can now download the file thru `Response.Redirect` but the button remains enable, it does not get disable after this :(

Comment: And what if to disable button and *then* redirect?

Comment: Then try to use the 2nd approach :). However, the 1st should work too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, the button should be disabled in client side (since you are using `Response.End()` in your code, ASP.NET will never render the page with the button having `Enabled=False`.

In your .aspx file add

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" [..] />
```

But also note that this might not be a good idea altogether - what if the user accidentally clicks "Cancel" from the file download window?

A better solution (understanding that you want to prevent the user from clicking the button multiple times) is to add a timer to re-enable the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSavetoDB_ExportToExcel" OnClientClick="var a=this; a.disabled=true; window.setTimeout(function() { a.disabled=false; }, 5000)" [..] />
```

Value `5000` is the time in miliseconds after which the button will be re-enabled.

Comment: when I added the OnClientClick code, the button becomes disable, but no code behind is executed :(